# React custom Hook using useRef returns null for the first time the calling component Loads?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a custom hook to scroll the element back into view when the component is scrolled.

```
export const useComponentIntoView = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const {current} = ref;
  if (current) {
    window.scrollTo(0, current.offsetTop );
  }
  return ref;
}
```

Now i am making use of this in a functional component like

```
<div ref={useComponentIntoView()}>
```

So for the first time the current always comes null, i understand that the component is still not mounted so the value is null . but what can we do to get this values always in my custom hook as only for the first navigation the component scroll doesn't work . Is there any work around to this problem .

Comment: how are you exporting useComponentIntoView? and, where did you set `createRef()`?

Comment: Is `useComponentIntoView` the same as `useScrollToTop`?

Comment: Yes it's the same my bad copying and pasting. The method call is the same name. Placing it on top of any div or components helps me get the ref but first time its null

Comment: The goal is to trigger the `scrollTo` on the first render right?

Comment: Yes . This is what is am trying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We need to read the `ref` from `useEffect`, when it has already been assigned. To call it only on mount, we pass an empty array of dependencies:

```
const MyComponent = props => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop);
        }
    }, []);

    return <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

In order to have this functionality out of the component, in its own Hook, we can do it this way:

```
const useComponentIntoView = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop);
        }
    }, []);

    return ref;
};

const MyComponent = props => {
    const ref = useComponentIntoView();

    return <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

We could also run the `useEffect` hook after a certain change. In this case we would need to pass to its array of dependencies, a variable that belongs to a state. This variable can belong to the same Component or an ancestor one. For example:

```
const MyComponent = props => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop);
        }
    }, [counter]);

    return (
        <div ref={ref}>
            <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter => counter + 1)}>
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

In the above example each time the button is clicked it updates the counter state. This update triggers a new render and, as the counter value changed since the last time `useEffect` was called, it runs the `useEffect` callback.

Comment: this works but in scenario where only the props changes to the component and not mounted again if we pass the deps as ref.current in the array of useEffect it doesn't execute the scroll again,

Comment: @RahulSingh in that case you need a state. Either the state holds the DOM element (not recommended) or the state holds a variable (whatever it is, it might just be a simple counter) that changes when you want `useEffect` to run.

Comment: i am thinking of adding this same condition `if (ref.current) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop);
        }` out side the use-effect which will be triggered on every rerender

Comment: But do you want to trigger `window.scrollTo` in every render?

Comment: yes for the first time alone the useeffect will run and then after that this method will have the ref.current and scroll to view . and useeffect will not get triggered as the component is not mounted everytime . ..

Comment: The problem is that with that solution every time a parent component renders this component will render and scroll. If you want it to scroll several times, the way to go is to use a state variable and pass it to the useEffect deps. When exactly should it scroll? What external change should trigger the scroll?

Comment: i think when the parent rerender then only i want the component to re render , but only on change of a certain prop , we need to add that check in the calling component i feel

Comment: If that prop is defined on the parent, you can pass it to the child and use it in the `useEffect` dependencies array.

Comment: was just doing that by adding a param to it yes , was doing that was trying that out only . let me see if that works in al my cases thanks aton

Comment: you could add this to your answer @Alvaro  if possible. it might be of help to others looking for a similar custom hook impl . and also want this on certain scenarios .

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, `ref.current` is `null` until after the component is mounted. This is where you can use `useEffect` - which will fire after the component is mounted, i.e.:

```
const useComponentIntoView = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop );
    }
  });

  return ref;
}
```